# Template :1: function "copyrightYear" not defined

Tags: go, template-engine

The following code panics at `tmp.Execute` saying `function "copyrightYear" not defined`

```
import (
    "os"
    "html/template"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    fm := template.FuncMap{
        "copyrightYear": func() string {
            return fmt.Sprintf("%d", time.Now().Year())
        },
    }
    tmp := template.Must(template.New("").Parse("{{copyrightYear}}")).Funcs(fm)
    tmp.Execute(os.Stdout, nil)
}
```

What am I missing? I've poked around the documentation.  Changing it to `call copyrightYear` in the template, or `copyrightYear .` doesn't fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
package main

import (
        "fmt"
        "html/template"
        "os"
        "time"
)

func main() {
        fm := template.FuncMap{
                "copyrightYear": func() string {
                        return fmt.Sprintf("%d", time.Now().Year())
                },
        }
        tmp := template.Must(template.New("").Funcs(fm).Parse("{{copyrightYear}}"))
        tmp.Execute(os.Stdout, nil)
}
```

[Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/qKUFU0mRpK)

---

Output:

```
2009
```

Comment: Is template.Funcs() returning a copy rather than the same object?

Comment: @ChristopherPfohl: Functions must be already defined when the template is being parsed. The other order is "too late" ;-)

Comment: huh...I guess that makes sense...I'll have to read the source... Thanks so much.